# Unity app icon loses transparency

Tags: unity-game-engine, icons, transparency

I have made the curved game icon for unity. But somehow it loses the transparency.
I am uploading an image for the understanding.

[image: Here it loses transparency]

[image]

Comment: You mean you don't want the black part behind the zombie face ?

Comment: @EmreE Yes. I have made that logo in curve shape just like most of the logos are but it showed in square shape.

Comment: What's the format of the image and which platform is the transparency missing?

Comment: @Programmer Format is Png, I am making it for android device.

Comment: Png seems fine for this. what happens when you disable "Alpha Is transparency" checkbox? Does it lose the transparency when imported in the Editor or when built for Android?

Comment: As all the possible solutions mentioned by developers is not working for you. Upload the icon so that we can try it in our codes to check for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while from the original question date, but I've faced the same problem and found the solution.

Make sure you got the following in your image inspector.

- Texture Type: Default
- Alpha Source: Input Texture Alpha
- Alpha Is Transparency: Checked

Done in Unity 2019.1.7f1

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you changed the type of the image from texture to sprite?

Comment: I have also changed it to Sprite(2D and UI). No luck.

Comment: can you show a updated screenshot of the icon with open inspector?